# Vision api not supporting camera autofocus

Tags: java, android, qr-code, barcode-scanner, vision-api

I am using **google vision api** for scanning QR code and barcode. It is not supporting camera autofocus and remains blurred when detecting a barcode. Although my device supports autofocus. I am using autofocus feature provided by vision api but its not working

```
cameraSource = new CameraSource
            .Builder(getActivity(), barcodeDetector)
            .setRequestedPreviewSize(1600, 1024)
            .setAutoFocusEnabled(true)
            .build();
```

Log is showing:

```
I/CameraSource: Camera auto focus is not supported on this device.
```

Please Help. How can I resolve this?

Comment: This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41629911/camerasource-setautofocusenabledtrue-returns-camera-auto-focus-is-not-suppor  Also it might be that the auto-focus is actually not supported

Comment: @Novo Lucas Thanks for suggestion but i have tried that as well and it didnt work. I am using it inside fragment

Comment: In your device is auto-focus supported?

Comment: Yes it supports autofocus. Other barcode scanners can focus it very well

Answer (score 0):

Try to update the sample code. The new version does not contain `setAutoFocusEnabled` method for `CameraSource.Builder`:

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/blob/master/visionSamples/barcode-reader/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/samples/vision/barcodereader/ui/camera/CameraSource.java

Comment: Should I use this class for **CameraSource**?

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it

Answer (score 0):

Your `CameraSource` should have a `setFocusMode(String mode)` method. Something like

```
builder.setFocusMode(
    autoFocus ? Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE : null);
```

should work. Where `autoFocus` is a boolean.